# Using sed command change a string on a certain line with a certain string

Tags: sed

I need to use sed  to change a string in a file only on the 4th line if it contains a string called "test"

So basically What I got right now is:

```
sed '/test/ s/abc/zz/g' sample
```

This will basically look through the lines and see if it has test and than change the abc to zz if its in that line.

But how do I do it only for the 4th line.

I tried

```
 sed '/test/ 4s/abc/zz/g' sample
```

Adding the 4 infront of the s , but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
sed -e '4 {
  /test/s/abc/zz/g
}' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but would something like this work?

```
awk 'NR==4 {print $0}' filename.txt | grep 'test' | sed 's/abc/xyz/g'
```

Answer (score -1):

another way:

first find the line with that string "test":

LINE=$(grep "test" file -n |  awk '{print $1}' | cut -d ':' -f1 | xargs)

then using that variable LINE do:

sed "s$LINEs/abc/zzz/g" file

Comment: The Q says '_use `sed` to change a string in a file only on the 4th line if it contains a string called "test"_'. How does your post answer the question ?

Comment: It specyfically does find the string and defines the line and then base on that line it replaces the proper string with a text provided, however there's is no 4 in this answer, so it's even simpler.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

```
sed -i '4s/old_text/new_text/g' file_name
```